# getting image object from DB2 and loading into local c drive

Tags: hibernate, db2

I am using DB2,Hibernate with spring.
    I have a table in DB2.
    This table contains BLOB for icon.
    I want to retrieve this icon image and to place this icon into our local drive.
    How can i do that?
    Can anybody help?

I am able to retrieve that list as JSON objects .After getting this, I want to iterate 
    this list in hibernate. Also want to do as i mentioned above.

In that list I am getting icon like

```
icon:"QzpFYXN5bG9jYWwgaW1hZ2VzcGlnZ2x5d2lnZ2x5LnBuZw=="
```

Also, In my local drive,icon images are stored. But it can't be displayed.
    What I will do now?

Please anyone help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code that get that blob and change that into file

Comment: @Angga I dnt know how to extract the binary data ( i.e icon image stored in DB2.) from db2.